# Route exists but doesn't work and deleted route still works Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, routes

Well, I was working on my project and suddenly when I created a new route I get this problem where the route exists but it shows 404 !! so I tried to delete an existing route that is working but when I delete that route still works !! I had this problem previously but I just deleted that route and made another route again and it was working fine but this time it does not work !!

Here is some of my code ->

```js
$("#resetBtn").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/reset/website/data",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            _token: $('meta[name="csrf"]').attr("content"),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            activateNotificationSuccess("Successfully reseted.");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            activateNotificationFail("Something went very wrong !!");
        },
    });   
});
```

```
Route::post('/reset/website/data', [ColorNImageController::class, 'reset']);
```

Here is the problem if I make it a get request and directly navigate using my browser ->

[image]

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: try url: "{{url('/reset/website/data')}}",

Comment: Did you cache your routes?

Comment: if not working then post full web.php .if you have prefix then you have to add prefix well or better create route names

Comment: I gues it's not a ajax problem because i tried to navigate using my browser with get request but still it shows 404

Comment: Is the route in the table that is returned by `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: Of course, the GET request shows 404 because you only defined the route for POST requests, didn't you?

Comment: shaedrich Thank you i cached my config but not routes so i did it and it works fine now!

Comment: No i changed it to get and tried it still shows 404 but now fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run the command line:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

Run following artisan commands

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Hope this will be useful.